# The current location is not visible on the map using MapKit

Tags: ios, objective-c, mapkit

I want to show the user's current location on map using `MapKit` and everything goes ok but the user current location is not visible on the maps.
Here are the properties I have set for `mapView`:

[image: mapView properties]

Here is rest of the controller's code:

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
#import "ShowMarkerAndNavigateVC.h"

@interface ShowMarkerAndNavigateVC ()

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapView;

@end

CLLocationManager *mgr;


@implementation ShowMarkerAndNavigateVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    NSLog(@"View loaded Successfully");
    mgr = [[CLLocationManager alloc] init];
    [mgr requestWhenInUseAuthorization];
    NSLog(@"Reuquested always authorization");
}

- (IBAction)backButtonPressed:(id)sender {
    [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
}


@end
```

I have also set the `mapView` delegate to the current controller as shown here: 
[image: mapView delegate]

The expected result is that it should show the user's current location.
The actual result is that it does not show location on the map as shown here:
[image: result on simulator]

Comment: Are you using a simulator? If you are, don't forget to simulate location using an. xCode.

Answer (score 0):

First, I would suggest actually setting `showsUserLocation` property to YES in code.

Second, note that it is up to you to show the region where the user location actually is; for example:

```
- (void)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView
        didUpdateUserLocation:(MKUserLocation *)userLocation {
    CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinate = userLocation.location.coordinate;
    MKCoordinateRegion reg =
        MKCoordinateRegionMakeWithDistance(coordinate, 600, 600);
    mapView.region = reg;
}
```

Comment: Now it shows the location but not the custom one which I set in the debug of emulator. Can you have some more detailed link on it as I new complete new to ios.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the simulator, you won't get the user's location, because the simulator doesn’t know its own location.

To do so, open the **Debug** menu of the Simulator and select *Apple* in the ***Location* sub-menu.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: I did the same but it did not resolve the problem. I also set a custom location but still no result.